# Facebook PHP SDK: Login with predefined username and password instead of login screen

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to create a php script that gets all the comments from a predefined status ID. I use the Facebook SDK for php. So now that I have it set up and running in my browser (with login link!!!), I would like it to run on my server without the login screen. Can I somehow login to Facebook programmatically with my own user credentials, so that my php script can run in the background without interaction ?

Comment: The API provides no functionality for that. Get an extended user access token, that’s valid for 60 days.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your answer! How do I get hold of such a token ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Comment: Thanks! Please answer this question, so that I can reward you! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API provides no functionality for that.

Get an extended user access token, that’s valid for 60 days: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/